# prove of disprove :'For every $x\in G$ there exists some $y\in G$ such that $x=y^2$, where $G$ is a group."

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am working on a question in the book: A Book of Abstract Algebra by Pinter. The question asks to prove or disprove the following statement:

For every $x\in G$ there exists some $y\in G$ such that $x=y^2$, where $G$ is a group.

Now I am quite stumped by this. I tried the following:
$$x=yy$$
thus
$$x^{-1} = y^{-1}y^{-1}$$
Now since $y \in G$ we need to find an element $z=y^{-1}$ such that $x z^2=e$. I am not sure if this is the way to go to show the final result. If someone could help me out along the way that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

P.S. Another approach might be
$$y^{-1}x = xy^{-1} =y$$
Now because a group is not always commutative this could imply the statement is untrue.... I am not sure.. Thanks!

Comment: Look for a counterexample, such as the group of residues $\pmod{2}$.

Comment: Ah thanks! I guess specifically choosing $x={1}$ we find that no other element satisfies $x=y^2$ in the group of residues $\mod 2$. Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: No problem - you are welcome.

Comment: Note that if $G$ is a finite group of odd order, this is actually true.

Comment: This is true in some groups and false in others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you consider the group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ i.e. the group of residues $\pmod{2}$ under addition, in which every element squared gives the identity, there can be no element whose "square" is equal to the non-identity element 1.

Answer (score 7):

Another very obvious counter example: In $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$ under mulitplication, there is no element such that $x^2 = -1$.

The statement is however true if $G$ is a finite group of odd order. To see this, let $|G| = 2n+1$. Then for any $x\in G$,

$$(x^{n+1})^2 = x^{2n+2} = x$$
since $x^{2n+1} = 1 $ by Lagrange. So $y=x^{n+1}$ would do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the group $S_3$ .

There exists no $x$ such that $x^2=(12)$

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @Slugger;my pleasure,if you feel that this answer is simple and good ,do consider accepting it

Comment: I have already accepted an answer I'm afraid

Comment: @Slugger;no worries, just suggested as its my first answer here